# How can I convert char pointer to __uint8_t array in C?

Tags: c

I need to convert a string (char*) to an array of __uint8_t. I know the latter is an alias of unsigned char but I can't figure it out how to proper convert it.

Example:

```
char *ssid = "XXXXX";
```

This is need cause I have to call an API that accepts only an array of __uint8_t and not char*.

```
struct WifiConfig {
    uint8_t ssid[32];
    uint8_t password[64];
};

struct WifiConfig wifi_config;
wifi_config.ssid = ???
```

If I try to cast:

```
wifi_config.ssid = (__uint8_t *) ssid;
```

I get the follow error:

```
error: assignment to expression with array type
     wifi_config.ssid = (__uint8_t *) ssid;
```

Sorry if that's a silly question, last time I've played with C I was a teen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just cast it when passing it to the API. The real question here is whether the API accepts a `const` string. What API are you using?

Comment: No C function receives or returns an array of any kind.  The language has no provision for it.  Wherever you think that's what's happening, very likely it's instead a pointer that's being passed or returned.  This is important because you can convert a `char *` to a different pointer type, but you cannot convert a pointer to an array.

Comment: Well your edit certainly changes things.  No, your API function (still) *does not* accept an array, but I guess it accepts either a `struct WifiConfig` or a pointer to one.

Comment: I have to populate ssid of that structure but the information is stored into a char *, so indeed I need to copy that information into WifiConfig.ssid which is an array of __uint8_t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just cast:

```
const char *name = "My Full Name";
yourAPIFunction((__uint8_t *) name);
```

Note: this violates const-correctness. You have to make sure `yourAPIFunction` doesn't mutate `name`. If it does, then you'll need to `memcpy` (and `free`!) it to a local variable, and provide it that, so its mutations don't effect the pooled-string used by any other users of `"My Full Name"`.

## Response to your (completely different) updated question:

Those arrays have their storage in-line, they're not pointers to the heap like a typical `char *`.. You need to copy the contents of your string into them:

```
// ssid must be at most 31 chars (plus NUL terminator)
// password must be at most 63 chars (plus NUL terminator)
struct WifiConfig new_wifi_config(char *ssid, char *password) {
    struct WifiConfig wifi_config;
    memcpy(wifi_config.ssid, ssid, strlen(ssid)+1)
    memcpy(wifi_config.password, ssid, strlen(ssid)+1)
    return wifi_config;
}
```

Comment: I've got an error when I've tried to do that: error: assignment to expression with array type
     current_config.ssid = (__uint8_t *) ssid;

Comment: No, @user2831450, you got an error when you tried to do *something different* from what Alexander recommended.  See also my comment on your question.

Comment: Thanks very much, that worked!! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to convert a string (char*) to an array of __uint8_t. I know
>   the latter is an alias of unsigned char but I can't figure it out how
>   to proper convert it.

Being pedantic -- because it matters here -- a C string is *not* a `char *`.  Rather, it is a null-terminated array of `char`.  These are accessed and handled primarily via pointers of type `char *`, largely because that's how one works with arrays in C.

Thus, no, you do not want to convert a `char *` to an array.  It appears that what you want to do is *copy the contents* of the array to which it points.  For your particular purpose I would use the `strncpy()` function:

```
strncpy((char *) wifi_config.ssid, ssid, sizeof(wifi_config.ssid));
```

Note well that with that code, if `ssid` is longer than `wifi_config.ssid` can accommodate then the latter will end up being unterminated, and that otherwise its tail will be filled out with null bytes.  Given the type of that array, such behavior may be *precisely* what is needed.  If you want to ensure null termination, however, then simply overwrite the last byte of the array with a 0 after the `strncpy()`.